# MPI error neither I (nor Google apparently) have never encountered before: "Assertion failure at ips_proto_expected.c:1703: buflen > 4"

Tags: multiprocessing, mpi, gfortran

I found ips_proto_expected.c at [github](https://github.com/01org/psm/blob/master/ptl_ips/ips_proto_expected.c), and it seems to be something feeling low level - clearly some buffer array is too small, but I never call anything like this directly. I'm running on a large computing cluster, and I encounter this error if I run on 2 nodes (of 12 processors each, 24 total), but it runs fine on 1 node (12 processors total). This makes me suspect it might be a compiler or hardware issue related to MPI. I've got this with both open-mpi and MPICH when using the gnu compilers. I've contacted the computing cluster's administrators, but as a long shot I'm wondering if anybody else has seen this error and knows the general sort of thing that causes it.

Edit: I found the solution after contacting my sysadmin (who contacted infiniband support), in case anybody else encounters this error. Apparently this is a "known problem" with the PSM library. It can be fixed by setting "export PSM_TID=0" at runtime. This apparently has a small effect on performance, so should only be used if you're hitting this error.

Comment: Have you examined a stack trace of what sequence of calls leads to that code? I'll note that's in the low-level PSM driver code that supports the specific QLogic-derived Infiniband network hardware in your cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after contacting my sysadmin, who in turn contacted infiniband support. Apparently this is a "known problem" with the PSM library. It can be fixed by setting "export PSM_TID=0" at runtime. This apparently has a small effect on performance, so should only be used if you're hitting this error.